# Use same jQuery function in multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, instances

I have this function and it needs to work in 54 different buttons on a page, what am I missing to make it work ONLY in the corresponding FLIP?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".flip").mouseenter(function() {
    $(".panel").slideDown("medium");
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".main").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".panel").slideUp("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
.panel,
.flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.panel {
  padding: 50px 5px;
  display: none;
}

.main {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="flip">This is FLIP 1</div>
  <div class="panel">This is the son of FLIP 1</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="flip">This is FLIP 2</div>
  <div class="panel">This is the son of FLIP 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$(this)` object and `siblings()` method like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".panel").slideDown("medium");
  });

  $(".flip").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".panel").slideUp("fast");
  });
});
```

**NOTE :** No need for two ready function just one is enough.

Hope this helps.

**Snippet using `mouseenter/mouseleave` :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".panel").slideDown("medium");
  });
  $(".flip").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".panel").slideUp("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
.panel,
.flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.panel {
  padding: 50px 5px;
  display: none;
}

.main {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="flip">This is FLIP 1</div>
  <div class="panel">This is the son of FLIP 1</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="flip">This is FLIP 2</div>
  <div class="panel">This is the son of FLIP 2</div>
</div>
```

**Snippet using `hover` :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( ".flip" ).hover(function() {
      $(this).siblings(".panel").slideDown("medium");
  }, function() {
      $(this).siblings(".panel").slideUp("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
.panel,
.flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
}

.panel {
  padding: 50px 5px;
  display: none;
}

.main {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="flip">This is FLIP 1</div>
  <div class="panel">This is the son of FLIP 1</div>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <div class="flip">This is FLIP 2</div>
  <div class="panel">This is the son of FLIP 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm!
I used the "mouseenter/mouseleave" snippet with a little twist, since I needed to be able to enter the "panel", so I used mouselave to work on "main" div:

`code`$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".panel").slideDown("medium");
  });

  $(".main").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".panel").slideUp("fast");
  });
});`code`

Comment: Accepted mark was removed from this post is there any problem in the provided answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery next to find the corresponding panel:

```
$(".flip").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).next('.panel').slideDown("medium");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$(".panel")` with `$(this).siblings('.panel')`. When you do `$(".panel")` then you are targeting all the `.panel` elements on your page and not just the one you want to work with.